RPG game objects with medieval graphics filter?
I want to create 3D scenes, but I don't have much time to add medieval-style artifacts to these scenarios. I believe that writing code in Blender 3D or a similar tool should help with this. Although the internet has a wealth of resources, they are limited in scope due to the lack of medieval resources. To give the players the impression that they are in the Middle Ages, I intend to create sceneries in 3D, gather the necessary items from the internet, bundle them together, and apply a medieval filter on top of them.
Can you say that there are already simple ways to accomplish this, or are there any online tools or presets? Where should I begin to think?

What are "medieval-style artifacts" and what do you mean by "medieval filter"? Do you have any specific examples or reference images? Is this a question about using Blender?
